# Drawing an image over a pdf using the Cairo vector graphics library

Tags: pdf, graphics, cairo

So I have looked at various open source libraries to render and create pdfs. I have found that it is possible to use Poppler and Cairo together to create and render pdf documents. My project requires the ability to draw images over a pdf document, so I was thinking about using cairo to do this. Is this possible?
Can I draw images (bitmaps) over an existing pdf file with Cairo?